# Clear Pin Cache for Smart Token in C#

Tags: c#, windows, smartcard

I'm working on C# application (.Net Framework) that uses smart tokens for signing and decryption operations. I want the pin to be provided each time token is accessed. I want to clear the pin cache.

I tried to use CryptSetProvParam function from Crypto API, but it fails with some models of tokens.

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CryptSetProvParam(IntPtr hProv, uint dwParam, IntPtr pvData, uint dwFlags);
```

I also tried to use functions in Cryptography Next Generation APIs, but it didn't work at all.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, smartcard uses CSP (Crypto Service Provider).  CSP of some of the smart card has option to store password.  Thus user may have to remove that option if selected by the user.  I have attached sample screen shot of Hypersecu ePass2003 Token Manager -> Settings.

[image: ePass2003 Token Driver remember password setting.]

Comment: How can I do this from C# code for different smart tokens models?

Comment: Every CSP uses it's own settings (stored in Windows Registry), thus there is no common method (known to me).  One may use PKCS#11 and call method *c_Logout* after every operation but this is driver dependent approach. Since user consciously chooses option in Smartcard CSP (Manager) to store his PIN, should not be a big problem.

Answer (score -1):

To cache in NetCore - Distributed caching, you can see this Microsoft Documentation [Distributed Caching NetCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-redis-cache)

You can use Redis to cache and remove as accordingly the token, see this short tutorial on how to get started with Redis on NET Core in no time. [how to get started with Redis on NET Core in no time.](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/redis-caching-in-aspnet-core/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm searching for.  I need to clear pin cache of smart token used in cryptographic operations